# UIAlertController (ActionSheet) - Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: swift, constraints

I'm getting this warning every time an UIAlertController action sheet is presented in a simulated phone.  The code is nothing fancy.

```
let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Action 1", style: .default) { _ in }
let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Action 2", style: .default) { _ in }
let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

alert.addAction(action1)
alert.addAction(action2)
alert.addAction(cancel)

self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

I'm running Xcode 10.2 (10E125), Swift 5. The constraint seems out of my control but please advise if I'm doing something wrong.

[image: screen capture]

Comment: Have you tried "reset to suggested constraints?" It appears that there are multiple view.width constraints.

Comment: Where might I find that?  I don't see it as an option on the UIAlertController instance.

Comment: Lower right corner of IB. See the screen shot in my answer. It's in the menu of the leftmost icon on the bottom. And, just for the record, I agree that IB seems to do some strange things while you're learning it.

Comment: Answer should be up. Hope it helps you.

Comment: I sort of have left & right confused in the previous comment. It's the rightmost icon. Sorry about that.

Comment: Clearly this is Apple’s bug. Let’s consolidate these repeated questions about it. File a bug report please.

Comment: Bug reported has been submitted.  I couldn't find a duplicate at the time of posting.

Answer (score -7):

Screenshot of IB showing the icons for constraint-manipulating menus. You can also click on the constraints themselves to edit or delete them.

[image: Picture from IB]

Check out the various drop-down menus.